# Several Implementations of a Domain-Model

Tags: oop, architecture, osgi

for a highly modular application (implemented with OSGi) we use one module just for the domain model. The implementations of the interfaces are just simple POJOs for most flexibility (other modules which depend on the domain-module don't inherit any other dependency).

So you could see the environment like this: There are just these simple domain-objects being passed from one module to the other. So we could call them POJO-DTOs, right? The DTOs don't know anything of there data storage.

With this architecture a module has a minimal dependency to that domain-model. Modules can be easily developed independently.

One problem we are facing is that a module can implement its own internal domain using the same interfaces of the domain-module. So the two implementations need to be copied from one side to the other. This is an error-prone thing!

Has anyone a good technique/concept/library to copy/merge two implementations with the same interfaces?

Thanks!

Comment: "So the two implementations need to be copied from one side to the other." => why ? Can you elaborate on the dependencies between modules with precise examples ?

Comment: we want to use aspects on the persistence modules on the domain-objects, we don't want to have these dependencies on each module. For example: org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity